# if they fail vs. if they should fail vs. if they were to fail (what's the difference in intensity or nuance?)

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> if they fail vs. if they should fail vs. if they were to fail

the only difference is tense: fail(present), should fail(modal past), were(be past)

Comment: This is by no means an authoritative rule, but to me _if they fail_ seems to regard failure as a realistic possibility, _if they should fail_ as a less likely possibility, and _if they were to fail_ (which, BTW, is the subjunctive) as a hypothetical case.

Comment: @KateBunting I suggest you (should) make an answer because your comment is helpful and crystal-clear.